# DeviceIoControl returning unexpected physical sector size

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel

I use `DeviceIoControl` to return the size of a physical disk sector. It has always returned 512 bytes, until lately where it started returing 4096 bytes. Inspecting the resulting `STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR` I see that the logical and physical byte sizes has switched places - should not the logial byte size of a disk sector always be greater or equal to the physical sector size?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Kernel32.lib")

int main()
{
    HANDLE hDevice;

    char cDisk = 'c';   // Get metadata about the C:\ disk

    // Build the logical drive path and get the drive device handle
    std::wstring logicalDrive = L"\\\\.\\";
    wchar_t drive[3];
    drive[0] = cDisk;
    drive[1] = L':';
    drive[2] = L'\0';
    logicalDrive.append(drive);

    hDevice = CreateFile(
        logicalDrive.c_str(),
        0, 
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error\n";
        return -1;
    }   

    // Now that we have the device handle for the disk, let us get disk's metadata
    DWORD outsize;
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY storageQuery;
    memset(&storageQuery, 0, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY));
    storageQuery.PropertyId = StorageAccessAlignmentProperty;
    storageQuery.QueryType  = PropertyStandardQuery;

    STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR diskAlignment = {0};
    memset(&diskAlignment, 0, sizeof(STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR));

    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice, 
        IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, 
        &storageQuery, 
        sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY), 
        &diskAlignment,
        sizeof(STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR), 
        &outsize,
        NULL)
        )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Physical sector size: " diskAlignment.BytesPerPhysicalSector << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Logical sector size: " diskAlignment.BytesPerLogicalSector << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result from running the above code is:

```
Physical sector size: 4096
Logical sector size: 512
```

Running `fsutil` gives the same unexpected result.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
NTFS Version   :                  3.1
LFS Version    :                  2.0
Number Sectors :                  0x000000001741afff
Total Clusters :                  0x0000000002e835ff
Free Clusters  :                  0x0000000000999d28
Total Reserved :                  0x0000000000003260
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :       4096
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you formatted that drive incorrectly. If you incorrectly mismatch the logical sector size and the physical sector size it will have a performance impact. (Logical Sector size should be the same as physical sector size)

Comment: @Mgetz It's a MacBook PRO running dual-boot Windows - did Apple format my SSD disk wrongly? What is weird is that I could swear the same code correctly returned 512 bytes just a couple of months ago.

Comment: Also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2011/06/28/ntfs-and-4k-disks.aspx?Redirected=true Hard to say, this could be alleviated in the UEFI firmware. There are a LOT of things that go into this, but I would not be surprised if the actual physical sector size was 4096.

Comment: More Related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Mgetz So these are the supposed "Advanced Format" or 512E (4K physical and 512-byte logical sector size) disks then?

Comment: I would think that would be highly likely

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong here. From 'File Buffering' article of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Application developers should take note of **new types of storage
>   devices being introduced into the market with a physical media sector
>   size of 4,096 bytes. The industry name for these devices is "Advanced
>   Format". As there may be compatibility issues with directly
>   introducing 4,096 bytes as the unit of addressing for the media, a
>   temporary compatibility solution is to introduce devices that emulate
>   a regular 512-byte sector storage device** but make available
>   information about the true sector size through standard ATA and SCSI
>   commands. As a result of this emulation, there are in essence two
>   sector sizes that developers will need to understand:
>
> - Logical Sector: The unit that is used for logical block addressing    for the media. We can also think of it as the smallest unit of write
>     that the storage can accept. This is the "emulation".
> - Physical Sector: The unit for which read and write operations to the    device are completed in a single operation. This is the unit of
>     atomic write, and what unbuffered I/O will need to be aligned to in
>     order to have optimal performance and reliability characteristics.

Answer (score -1):

The 4096 byte is 8 sectors and called cluster. When you save a file, you save into one or more cluster. If the file has a size greater than 512 byte it will be saved into a cluster. The empty sectors are called slack. Some malware writes themselves into empty sectors to hide in plain sight. FAT file system uses 16 or 32 sectors for one cluster.